# How fixed Method DELETE with Angular 5

Tags: angular, html, http-delete

I develop CRUD in my application with Angular 5, the method GEt and POST is work, but method DELETE isn't work (remove dynamic data), i have this error:

```
 DELETE http://172.16.47.34:8282/MyProject.webservices/api/Roles?UID={UID} 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

how fixed this error and thank's

this my code .html :

```
....
(click)="onDelete()"
...
```

and this my code .ts:

```
export interface Role {
  RoleName: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-role',
  templateUrl: './role.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./role.component.css']
})
export class RoleComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  private roles: any;
  constructor(private _roleService: RoleService, private http: HttpClient) { }

  onSubmit(role: Role) {
    return this.http.post('http://172.16.47.34:8282/MyProject.webservices/api/Roles', role).subscribe(status => console.log(JSON.stringify(status)));
  }

  onDelete(role: Role) {
    return this.http.delete('http://172.16.47.34:8282/MyProject.webservices/api/Roles?UID={UID}', role).subscribe(status => console.log(JSON.stringify(status)));
  }

  onUpdate(role: Role) {
    return this.http.put('http://172.16.47.34:8282/MyProject.webservices/api/Roles', role).subscribe(status => console.log(JSON.stringify(status)));
  }
```

Comment: it seems you have a server error, have a look at the server logs to see what is happening.

Comment: you can't have body in delete request.

Comment: but How to fix this problem !

Comment: Have you even looked at the error on the server side?

Answer (score 0):

you can't pass Object in DELETE request meaning delete request can't have body

below is wrong

```
onDelete(role: Role) {
    return this.http.delete('http://172.16.47.34:8282/MyProject.webservices/api/Roles?UID={UID}', role).subscribe(status => console.log(JSON.stringify(status)));
  }
```

instead it should be like

```
onDelete(role: Role) {
    return this.http.delete('http://172.16.47.34:8282/MyProject.webservices/api/Roles?UID={UID}').subscribe(status => console.log(JSON.stringify(status)));
  }
```

or

```
onDelete(role: Role) {
    return this.http.delete('http://172.16.47.34:8282/MyProject.webservices/api/Roles?UID={UID}', {headers: headersVariable}).subscribe(status => console.log(JSON.stringify(status)));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

As Pratap A.K already mentioned, you have to call the `delete` method in another way. Refer the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#delete) for more details.

Here is an example:

```
onDelete(role: Role) {
  const url = `http://172.16.47.34:8282/MyProject.webservices/api/Roles?UID=${role.id}`;
  return this.http.delete(url).subscribe(status => 
    console.log(JSON.stringify(status))
  );
}
```

Comment: thank's for your answer, i use your example, but the same error !

Comment: The property `id` was just an example. This depends on your implementation of the `Role` class and what needs to be passed to your webservice. Typically it's an identifier. So just replace the `id` parameter with the roles identifier property.